# Can't figure out how to solve this here: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception, tokenize

My problem is the following:

I have a 15k-line .train file for Apache NLP and this is a sample of what the whole text looks like:

```
La joven Estefania Lopez Montesinos de la comision <START:falla> Embarcadero  Historiador Beti <END> y la niña Maria Donderis Sanchis de la Falla <START:falla> Blasco Ibáñez  Plaza Maestro Ripoll <END>
```

As you see, the tags are wrapped between `<START:category>tag<END>` and the tags might have more than just one word.

What I need to do is to convert this huge text file into one looking like this:
(that is to say I need to separate each line by tokens and then in a tab-separated column I have to put an ‘O’ if the token is not a tag or the category (always falla) in my text if it’s a tag )

```
La  O
joven   O
Estefanía   O
Lopez   O
Montesinos  O
de  O
la  O
comisión    O
Embarcadero FALLA
Historiador FALLA
Beti    FALLA
y   O
la  O
niña    O
María   O
Donderis    O
Sanchez O
de  O
la  O
falla   O
Blasco  FALLA
Ibañez  FALLA
Plaza   FALLA
Maestro FALLA
Ripoll  FALLA
```

In order to create a file with the form of the latter text I have created a class which receives line by line from the first text and operates like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Tokenizer {
    public static ArrayList<Token> inspect (String input){
        ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();


        if(input.contains("<START:falla>")){
            String[] chunks = input.split("<START:falla>");
            for(String piece : chunks){
                if(piece.contains("<END>")){
                    String[] polaridad = piece.trim().split("<END>");
                    String falla = polaridad[0]; // Here is where I get the error.
                    String[] falles = falla.trim().split( " " );
                    for(String s : falles){
                        if ( !s.trim().isEmpty() ){
                            Token word = new Token(s);
                            word.setType(true);
                            tokens.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                    if(polaridad.length>1){
                        String weird = polaridad[1];
                        if(!weird.isEmpty()){
                            String[] nofalles = weird.trim().split( " " );
                            for(String s : nofalles){
                                if ( !s.trim().isEmpty() ){
                                    Token word = new Token(s);
                                    word.setType(false);
                                    tokens.add(word);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }       

                }else{  // if(!piece.contains("<END>"))
                    String[] pieces = piece.trim().split(" ");
                    for(String s : pieces){
                        if ( !s.trim().isEmpty() ){
                            Token word = new Token(s);
                            word.setType(false);
                            tokens.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            // splits using spaces
            String[] firstPass = input.trim().split( " " );

            for ( String s : firstPass ) {
                // the current part cannot be empty
                if ( !s.trim().isEmpty() ){
                    Token word = new Token(s);
                    word.setType(false);
                    tokens.add(word);
                }
            }
        }   
        return tokens;      
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this class I set the attribute 'setType' to every word so I can write the file in the specified format afterwards.

I don't know how to fix this as this same class was working flawlessly with another text.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You added the [tag:indexoutofboundsexception] tag but didn't read it?

Comment: Yes, I did, and if you read my question you'll see it was working before with another text. Therefore, I come here and ask.

Comment: You get the exception because `polaridad` is empty.

Comment: And if you knew more about indexoutofboundsexception you would know it occurs based on input. Meaning that the new text is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `piece` is equal to `<END>`. The documentation of `String.split(String)` says:

> "Trailing empty strings are [therefore] not included in the resulting array."

So, the following yields a zero-length array:

```
String piece = "<END>"
piece.trim().split("<END>") => []
```

If you want to keep empty trailing tokens, pass a negative second argument to `split`, and you get an array of length 2:

```
piece.trim().split("<END>", -1) => [, ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew the solution was simple.